# python : pandas: remove duplicates from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe  like the one below:

```
   A    B  
 chair  bed  
 bed    chair  
 spoon  knife  
 plate  cup
```

So, row 1 and 2 are duplicates for me and I want them removed. How can I do this in a simple way?

So after removing duplicates I will have:

```
  A     B      
spoon knife  
plate  cup
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with converted mask by `~`:

```
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['A','B']], axis=1)).duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Another slowier solution:

```
df = df[~df[['A','B']].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated(keep=False)]
```

---

```
print (df)
       A      B
2  spoon  knife
3  plate    cup
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['A','B']], axis=1)))
       0      1
0    bed  chair
1    bed  chair
2  knife  spoon
3    cup  plate

print (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['A','B']], axis=1)).duplicated(keep=False))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [441]: %%timeit
     ...: df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['A','B']], axis=1)).duplicated(keep=False)]
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 9.38 ms per loop

In [442]: %%timeit
     ...: df[~df[['A','B']].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated(keep=False)]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 4.46 s per loop

#jpp solution
In [443]: %%timeit
     ...: df['C'] = list(map(frozenset, df[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()))
     ...: df.drop_duplicates('C', keep=False).drop('C', 1)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 28.4 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using `frozenset`:

```
df['C'] = list(map(frozenset, df[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()))
df = df.drop_duplicates('C', keep=False).drop('C', 1)
```

**Result**

```
       A      B
2  spoon  knife
3  plate    cup
```

**Explanation**

- First create `frozenset` column 'C' from 'A' and 'B'.
- Drop duplicates, setting `keep=False`, and drop column 'C'.
- `frozenset` is required instead of `set` since sets are not hashable.